# How much data/information should be open?

Tags: usaidopen

How much information should be published for public. Implementing partners deal with beneficiary data. Should it be open to all? To what extent?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "partners deal" and "beneficiary data"? With examples. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Per [Project Open Data](https://project-open-data.cio.gov/principles/), data should be "complete" and published "with the finest possible level of granularity that is practicable and permitted by law and other requirements. Derived or aggregate open data should also be published but must reference the primary data."  Please see our [FAQ#8](http://www.usaid.gov/data/frequently-asked-questions#Q8) for a discussion of aggregate data.

Answer (score 2):

We recognize that partners work with beneficiary data, but the [terms of partner awards](http://www.usaid.gov/data/frequently-asked-questions#Q16) with USAID state that partners "must ensure that any Dataset submitted to the DDL does not contain any proprietary or personally identifiable information, such as social security numbers, home addresses, and dates of birth. Such information must be removed prior to submission."  Please see our [FAQ#21 for more information regarding sensitive data](http://www.usaid.gov/data/frequently-asked-questions#Q21).  There are many web-based resources on best practices for de-identifying data to protect personally identifiable information.  USAID implementing partners must [register the datasets](http://www.usaid.gov/data/ddlsubmissions) with USAID's Development Data Library.  The extent to which the datasets ultimately become public is determined by USAID's internal [data clearance process](http://www.usaid.gov/sites/default/files/documents/1880/DataPublicationProcess05-21-2014.pdf).  [FAQ#34](http://www.usaid.gov/data/frequently-asked-questions#Q34) provides additional information on the extent to which the data may be used and accessed post-publication.